# HTML: Table to Div

Tags: html, html-table

I have a table in HTML.
Now I need using DIV, don't use table.
Please tell me the way to do it.
This is the first my work with web, js, html, etc...
I actually don't have enough knowledge about it.
Hope you will tell me a link to learn basic knowledge.

```
var table_data="<TABLE border='1' WIDTH='100%'>";
    table_data +="<TR>";
        table_data +="<TD>TicketID</TD>";
        table_data +="<TD>Name</TD>";
        table_data +="<TD>Birthday</TD>";
        table_data +="<TD>Delete</TD>";
    table_data +="</TR>";
    $.each(data.list, function(i,list)
    {
        table_data +="<TR>";
        table_data +="<TD>"+list.account.ticketid+"</TD>";
        table_data +="<TD>"+list.account.name+"</TD>";
        table_data +="<TD>"+list.account.birthday+"</TD>";
        table_data +="<TD><input type='button' value='Delete' id='"+list.account.ticketid+"'/></TD>";
        table_data +="</TR>";
    });

    table_data +="</TABLE>";
    $(table_data).appendTo("#content");
```

I don't have enough point to up image
so, this is my webview....

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/713/webn.png/

Comment: that's not a table - that's the JS code generating the table. Please show your resulting HTML output

Comment: Why are you changing to a DIV? What have you tried? SO is not a site for people to do your work for you.

Comment: I think about view this web with another enviroment.
But i dont have enough knowledge about web, html, js...
this is first I work with web, etc...

Comment: @Zoltan TOth: I show my web here  .. http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/713/webn.png/

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
var table_data='<div id="table">';
    table_data +='<div class="row">';
        table_data +='<div class="cell">TicketID</div>';
        table_data +='<div class="cell">Name</div>';
        table_data +='<div class="cell">Birthday</div>';
        table_data +='<div class="cell">Delete</div>';
    table_data +='</div> <br>';
    $.each(data.list, function(i,list)
    {
        table_data +='<div class="row">';
        table_data +='<div class="cell">'+list.account.ticketid+'</div>';
        table_data +='<div class="cell">'+list.account.name+'</div>';
        table_data +='<div class="cell">'+list.account.birthday+'</div>';
        table_data +='<div class="cell"><input type="button" value="Delete" id="'+list.account.ticketid+'"/></div>';
        table_data +='</div> <br>';
    });

    table_data +='</div>';
    $(table_data).appendTo("#content");
```

Comment: but it view this web like a .... column @@
I think i need show all of my index.jsp

Comment: Why exactly do you have to use divs instead of table?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the code pattern below:

```
var table_data = $("<div/>");
table_data.attr("id", "table");

var table_row = $("<div/>");
table_row.addClass("row");

table_data.append(table_row);
```

when adding text,

```
table_row.append(list.account.name);
```

It is not a good practice to just concatenate string to build html tags.

Answer (score 0):

If the markup for the table is static, and not being loaded dynamically, I really recommend you have a look at Scaffolding @ http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html

The way it'll work is you will need to include the css and javascript files (download a zip on the home page of the link above) and then you will access to a beautiful, responsive, fluid system.

Although there is a very nice write-up on it on the site, I'll give you a quick run through.

To use it as a table, you first need the main container, it's just a div with the class 'container-fluid':

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Main Container -->
</div>
```

Within this, you have access to 12 columns which you can manipulate freely and unlimited rows. Let's add a new row with the heading 'Table -> Div', this is also a simple div but with the class 'row-fluid':

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Main Container -->
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <!-- First row -->
        Test -&gt; Div
    </div>
</div>
```

Now let's make a 3 x 3 magic square, each column is defined in the row as a div with the class 'span[number]' where number is the size (max is 12, as I said). So if we've got 3 columns, then our number would be 3/12 which is 3.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Main Container -->
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <!-- First row -->
        Test -&gt; Div
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4">
            4
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            9
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4">
            2
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            5
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            7
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4">
            8
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            6
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And voila, it's a floating magic square. From here, you can use basic CSS to 'theme' it. I didn't use your example because I don't want to give away the answer, just provide you with what you need to learn it.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. And you can inbox me at anytime if you need any sort of help with web development. XD